# How can I remove JSON property stored in a SQL Server column?

Tags: sql-server, json

I have a task to remove a JSON property saved in a SQL Server database table's column. Here is the structure of my table

```
OrderId   Name   JSON
```

In the `JSON` column I have this JSON data:

```
{ 
    "Property1" :"",
    "Property2" :"",
    "metadata-department": "A",
    "metadata-group": "B"
}
```

I have over 500 records that have this json value.

Can I update all the records to remove `metadata-department`?

Answer (score 34):

This question is old but I thought I'd post another solution for those who may end up here via search engine.

In SQL Server 2016 or SQL Azure, the following works:

```
DECLARE @info NVARCHAR(100) = '{"name":"John","skills":["C#","SQL"]}'

PRINT JSON_MODIFY(@info, '$.name', NULL)

-- Result: {"skills":["C#","SQL"]}
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921892.aspx

Comment: Worth mentioning that this approach only works if you're in *lax* mode (which is the default), if you're in *strict* mode then this will set the value of the node to be `null` instead of removing it.

Answer (score 0):

In my SQL Server environment, I have installed CLR RegEx Replace functions and using these, I've achieved what you wanted:

```
DECLARE @Text NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{ 
    "Property1" :"",
    "Property2" :"",
    "metadata-department": "A",
    "metadata-group": "B"
}';

PRINT dbo.RegExReplace(@Text, '"metadata-department": "[A-Za-z0-z]",\r\n\s+', '');
```

**Result:**

```
{ 
    "Property1" :"",
    "Property2" :"",
    "metadata-group": "B"
}
```

CLR Source: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL the function is `JSON_REMOVE()`:

`UPDATE orders SET JSON=JSON_REMOVE(JSON, '$.metadata-department')`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-remove