# Entity Framework Core 8 and JSON problems

Tags: json, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

I have many problems with managing JSON columns in EF Core 8:

1. If I add properties to the class I'm saving to JSON and there is already data in the table without this property, it will throw an error that the property does not exist.
   It is like EF expect that the property in JSON in db needs to exist for this class.
   How to manage adding properties to classes that are saved as JSON in EF because I can't use migrations for JSON objects?
2. I removed some properties from classes that is saved as JSON in the database. Now when I try to load the entity, it throws an error:

   > "Index was out of range"

   Then I need to comment out the entire JSON configuration to load the entity itself.

How to manage removing properties from classes that are saved as JSON in EF Core 8?

Update1...

```cs
public class User
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public UserSettings? Settings {get;set;}
}

public class UserSettings
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<UiSetting> UiSettings {get;set;} = new();
}

public class UiSetting 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

and it is mapped like this:

```cs
builder.Entity<User>(b=>
{
    b.ToTable("Users");
    b.HasKey(x=>x.Id);
    b.OwnsOne(x=>x.Settings, cfg=>
    {
        cfg.ToJson();
        cfg.WithOwner();
        cfg.OwnsMany(x=>x.UiSettings, pcfg=>pcfg.WithOwner());
    }  
}
```

Everything is ok and working, and I can save/load Users.

Now if I add a new property to UserSetting ie.

```cs
public class UserSettings
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<UiSetting> UiSettings {get;set;} = new();
    
    public List<DeviceSetting> DeviceSettings {get;set;} = new();
}

public class DeviceSetting
{
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public string Value {get;set;}
}

builder.Entity<User>(b=>
{
    b.ToTable("Users");
    b.HasKey(x=>x.Id);
    b.OwnsOne(x=>x.Settings, cfg=>
    {
        cfg.ToJson();
        cfg.WithOwner();
        cfg.OwnsMany(x=>x.UiSettings, pcfg=>pcfg.WithOwner());
        cfg.OwnsMany(x=>x.DeviceSettings, pcfg=>pcfg.WithOwner());
    }  
}
```

Now the problems begins.
If there is already data in User.Settings column and I try to load/update/save User I get error that the property DeviceSettings does not exist and it is an error thrown by SQL server itself. And to make it work again, I need to update every row in Users table and manually change Settings json to add missing new property.

Then...
If I remove property from UserSetting
Ie.

```cs
public class UserSettings
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    //public List<UiSetting> UiSettings {get;set;} = new();
    
    public List<DeviceSetting> DeviceSettings {get;set;} = new();
}

builder.Entity<User>(b=>
{
    b.ToTable("Users");
    b.HasKey(x=>x.Id);
    b.OwnsOne(x=>x.Settings, cfg=>
    {
        cfg.ToJson();
        cfg.WithOwner();
        //cfg.OwnsMany(x=>x.UiSettings, pcfg=>pcfg.WithOwner());
        cfg.OwnsMany(x=>x.DeviceSettings, pcfg=>pcfg.WithOwner());
    }  
}
```

And then I try to load users:

```cs
await DbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>x.Name=="someusername");
```

I get `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter "Index"` 
So now my question is how do I manage schema changes to classes saved as JSON columns?

Comment: The class should be able to handle *all* possible values. The problems you encounter are the same for all document databases, and the reason why storing JSON or XML data is *not* a magic bullet. If the data's shape is flexible, it's up to the application to handle all variants. Missing properties can be handled by making them nullable. More serious changes may require modifying all the existing data

Comment: I added properties as nullable just to avoid these errors. But it seems EF is treating the class as it was declared the first time. In document databases (RavenDB) You can version documents, and it automatically handles removal and adding of properties. But this is not related to my question. As I understood the JSON column does not require a fixed schema. There would be no meaning of using a JSON column if i need a fixed schema - I would just use a table instead.

Comment: Post the classes and examples of the JSON fields. `EF is treating the class as it was declared the first time` no, EF is *deserializing* the JSON column as-is into the current entity class. The lack of a JSON schema means EF has no way of knowing either what's stored in those text fields or if there are any mismatches. It can only try to deserialize the text. EF is an ORM - a Mapper, not a document database.

Comment: I added code samples

Comment: I agree with @PanagiotisKanavos.  I came across the same issue.  In cases where I needed to keep the property for historical data, I just left the property and made it nullable.  In other cases where I wanted the property completely gone from ALL records including historical records, I used JSON_MODIFY to completely remove the property from the underlying JSON.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40550523/11376319

Comment: Yes, I can use JSON_MODIFY to do it. But, would there be a more elegant way of doing this like ie. Migrations? If I don't use ToJson() and serialize/deserialize those classes manually, I have no problem but then I can't use filtering and other advanced stuff on it. In my opinion we need a way to configure serialization settings to Ignore unexisting properties...

Comment: Sounds like you *don't* want JSON at all then, but a better database design. You can't query or filter JSON even with SQL unless you  parse it. You can't create indexes on those fields, so if you try to filter based on the JSON contents, you'll have to scan all table rows.

Comment: If I understood correctly, it seems like you've hit one of the limitations of EF Core 8 as stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew#current-limitations   

Issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/31376